# Program to find sum of elements in a given array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have to find the elements in a given array, and I found a program in other site, but when I try to interpret the code in my way, I have error.

That is from the other site:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// function to return sum of elements
// in an array of size n
int sum(int arr[], int n)
{
    int sum = 0; // initialize sum

    // Iterate through all elements
    // and add them to sum
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        sum += arr[i];

    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 12, 3, 4, 15 };
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    cout << "Sum of given array is " << sum(arr, n);
    return 0;
}
```

That's mine:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int Function(int arr[], int Broi)
{
    int suma = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Broi; i++) {
        cin >> arr[Broi];
        suma += arr[i];
    }
    return suma;
}

int main()
{
    int arr;
    int Broi = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    cout << "Srednoto Aritmetichno e: " << Function(arr[], broi);
    return 0;
}
```

Also the first programe gives the numbers of the array, but I want the user to cin>> them when u write the length of the arr.

Comment: A `std::vector` and push_back would be a much better `c++` solution.

Comment: `int arr;` this is a single integer. It's not an array.

Comment: What's the error? A wrong result? That would be because you write to `arr[Broi]` but add `arr[i]`. You don't need to use an array at all. Just read the number into an `int` and add that to `suma`. You aren't using the individual numbers anywhere

Comment: We haven't studied Vectors yet.

Comment: Then you either have to make a large fixed sized array or dynamically allocate using new and possibly resize by allocating a new dynamic array and copy the contents of the old then swap pointers and remove the old.

Comment: The error is: [Error] invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript

Comment: You could do `int arr[1000];` then tell the user that he/she can't add any more after 1000 are used.

Comment: `cin >> arr[Broi];` should be `cin >> arr[i];`

Comment: The task is to read 10 numbers, and to put them in array.

Comment: Although do you even need an array for this problem? You can sum any number of user inputs without using an array at all.

Comment: int Broi = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); On this row gives the mistake where is arr[0]

Comment: We are studying arrays, and the teacher wants it like that.

Comment: For your case of 10 inputs you can do this: `const int Broi = 10; int arr[Broi];` and then fix the cin as stated above.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've forgotten about the const!

Comment: Side note: With an up-to-date compiler you can replace `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])` with `std::size(arr)`. Note that  for either to work, `arr` must be an array, and that array cannot have [decayed to a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay) by passing it to a function or performing math on it.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is not declaring an array at all.  It is declaring a single `int`.

You said in comments that:

> The task is to read 10 numbers, and to put them in array

So, you should declare a 10-`int` array in `main()` and fill it with user values *before* passing it to `Function()`, similar to how the original code was doing.  The user input doesn't really belong in `Function()` to begin with.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int Function(int arr[], int Broi)
{
    int suma = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Broi; i++) {
        suma += arr[i];
    }
    return suma;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[10];

    cout << "Enter 10 numbers: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    cout << "The sum is: " << Function(arr, 10);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The line `arr[Broi]` is accessing the array out of bounds, causing undefined behavor, because the array consists only of a single element. Even if it consisted of `Broi` elements, it would be accessing the array out of bounds, because valid indexes would be `0` to `Broi - 1`.

In the comments section (but not in the question), you stated that you are supposed to read `10` numbers from the user. If `arr` were pointing to an array of `10` elements instead of `1` element, then it would make sense to write `arr[i]` instead of `arr[Broi]`.

The simplest solution to the problem would be to not use arrays at all:

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr int NUM_INPUTS = 10;

int main()
{
    int input;
    int sum = 0;

    for ( int i = 0; i < NUM_INPUTS; i++ )
    {
        //prompt user for input
        std::cout << "Please enter integer #" << i + 1 << ": ";

        //attempt to read integer from user
        if ( ! ( std::cin >> input ) )
        {
            std::cout << "Input failure!\n";
            return 1;
        }

        //add user input to sum
        sum += input;
    }

    //print sum
    std::cout << "\nThe sum of all numbers is: " << sum << ".\n";

    return 0;
}
```

However, since you stated in the comments section that you are supposed to use arrays, then you are probably supposed to first read all `10` numbers from `std::cin` into an array of `10` elements and then calculate the sum afterwards:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

constexpr int NUM_INPUTS = 10;

void input_array( int arr[] )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < NUM_INPUTS; i++ )
    {
        //prompt user for input
        std::cout << "Please enter integer #" << i + 1 << ": ";

        //attempt to read integer from user
        if ( ! ( std::cin >> arr[i] ) )
        {
            std::cout << "Input failure!\n";
            std::exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
    }
}

int calculate_sum( int arr[] )
{
    int sum = 0;

    for ( int i = 0; i < NUM_INPUTS; i++ )
    {
        sum += arr[i];
    }

    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[NUM_INPUTS];

    //fill array with user input
    input_array( arr );

    //print sum
    std::cout << "\nThe sum of all numbers is: " << calculate_sum( arr ) << ".\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Both programs have the following output:

```
Please enter integer #1: 20
Please enter integer #2: 30
Please enter integer #3: 10
Please enter integer #4: 5
Please enter integer #5: 31
Please enter integer #6: 17
Please enter integer #7: 6
Please enter integer #8: 14
Please enter integer #9: 18
Please enter integer #10: 50

The sum of all numbers is: 201.
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple fix without too many complicated features would be like below:

```
#include <iostream>

int Function( int* const array, const std::size_t elementCount)
{
    int suma { };

    for ( std::size_t idx = 0; idx < elementCount; ++idx )
    {
        std::cin >> array[ idx ];
        suma += array[ idx ];
    }

    return suma;
}

int main( )
{
    int myArray[ 4 ] { };
    int suma = Function( myArray, sizeof( myArray ) / sizeof( *myArray ) );
    std::cout << "Srednoto Aritmetichno e: " << suma << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

That's it. You can change the size of `myArray` to anything that fits onto stack memory.